# Spring Cloud Vault With k2 v2 - How to Avoid 403 at Startup?

Tags: hashicorp-vault, spring-cloud-vault-config

## Problem

Does anyone know how to configure `bootstrap.yml` to tell Spring Cloud Vault to go to the correct path for k2 v2 and not try other paths first?

### Details

I can successfully connect to my Vault, running k2 v2, but Spring Cloud will always try to connect to paths in the vault that don't exist, throwing a 403 on startup.

```
Status 403 Forbidden [secret/application]: permission denied; nested exception is org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException$Forbidden: 403 Forbidden
```

The above path, `secret/application`, doesn't exist because k2 v2 puts `data` in the path. For example: `secret/data/application`.

This isn't a show-stopper because Spring Cloud Vault *does* check other paths, including the correct one that has the `data` item in the path, but the fact a meaningless 403 is thrown during startup is like a splinter in my mind.

*Ultimately, it does try the correct k2 v2 path*

```
2019-03-18 12:22:46.611  INFO 77685 --- [  restartedMain] b.c.PropertySourceBootstrapConfiguration : Located property source: CompositePropertySource {name='vault', propertySources=[LeaseAwareVaultPropertySource {name='secret/data/my-app'}
```

#### My configuration

```
    spring.cloud.vault:
      kv:
        enabled: true
        backend: secret
        profile-separator: '/'
        default-context: my-app
        application-name: my-app
      host: localhost
      port: 8200
      scheme: http
      authentication: TOKEN
      token: my-crazy-long-token-string
```

**Thanks for your help!**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add the following lines in your bootstrap.yml, this disables the generic backend

```
spring.cloud.vault:
  generic:
    enabled: false
```

for more information https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-vault/reference/html/#vault.config.backends.generic

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the accepted answer it's important to turn off (or just remove) `fail-fast` option:

```
spring.cloud.vault:
  fail-fast: false
```

Answer (score 0):

`spring.cloud.vault.generic.enabled` is deprecated in spring-cloud 3.0.0, but the 403 error is still there. To disable the warning (by telling spring to use the exact context), this is what I used:

```
spring:
  config:
    import: vault://
  application:
    name: my-application
  cloud:
    vault:
      host: localhost
      scheme: http
      authentication: TOKEN
      token: my-crazy-long-token-string
      kv:
        default-context: my-application
```

Other configs were set to default (such as port = 8200, backend = secret, etc.)